# Setting values in dropdown from the particular values of a Map

Tags: grails

I created a Map in my controller and passing it to View.I have a drop down list that populates the values from a database.The values are "1","2","3".I want to select the dropdown from the values of Map
like for 1st dropdown list,the selected value will be the first element of Map and for next dropdown the selected value will be the second value of the Map and so on,I guess it can be done from the value attribute of the select tab but how?Any help is appreciated

e.g

I created a Map in the controller and passing it to view

```
def Population={

def scores=["1":2,"2":3,"3":2,"4":2,"5":3,"6":1]

return new ModelAndView("/scores/scoreCheck",scores)

}
```

And in the view I am using it like below

```
<td><g:select name="SCBFScore" id="SCBFScore" from="${Decode.findAllByAttributeShortName('HASCORE1').collect{it.attributeCodeText}}" 
value="${scores?.get('1')}" noSelection="${['':'Select...']}"
</td>
```

My requirement is to select the dropdown list with the value of key "1" of Map scores.
Here the query

```
 Decode.findAllByAttributeShortName('HASCORE1').collect{it.attributeCodeText}
```

returning ["1","2","3"]

Thanks for the reply

I have a functionality for a player of his run scores for last 6 years.I have a module that a player can see or update his scores but can not create a whole new score. The data of his all score should be loaded from another source.When the application loads it will load the latest score he has.He has three level of scores "1","2","3" so he can score only one out of three.I want to preset the value of the scores in the view when the application loads initially with the data of the last score.

e.g
In the controller I exctracted all the 6 years scores and stores in a Map so the Map has the score in the format

['score of 2012':'2',[score of 2011:'3'],[score of 2011]:'1',[score of 2010]:'2' ] etc

So suppose in year 2012 a player score is 2
so when the the view loads it will preset the combobox with 2 for year 2012,the combobox will have value 1,2,3

so for year 2011
the view preset the dropdown list for year 2011 to 3,the combo box will have value 1.2,3

I thought like this way,please suggest if there are some better way to do this or you need some more detail

Answer (score 1):

The *value* attribute of the g:select has different purpose. If you're filling the g:select from a list of domain objects, you can specify the domain class attribute, which is used for storing the *value* - or presetting, if it already contains some value.

Simple example. You have a domain Menu and Conten,t and in the Menu you want to assign default Content (snipet from my code, 'menuInstance' is the actual domain object, I am working with):

```
<g:select name="defaultContent.id"
          from="${my.package.Content.list()}"
          optionKey="id"
          value="${menuInstance?.defaultContent?.id}" />
```

I understand your goal so: you want to pass to the view a map with multiple list of values for each of the listboxes, correct? So you should create the map in the controller like this:

```
return [ 'listbox1': list1, 'listbox2':list2 ]
```

and in the view you just use the 'listbox1' to the *from* attribute of the g:select.

So after your further explanation, I would rather use some DTO, to solve the problem. Under your src/groovy (or src/java) create a DTO:

```
public class ScoreDTO {
  String season
  int score

  public String toString() { return "Season $season: $score" }
}
```

In your controller it should look like:

```
ScoreDTO score1 = new ScoreDTO( season:'2012', score:3 )
ScoreDTO score2 = new ScoreDTO( season:'2011', score:1 )
ScoreDTO score3 = new ScoreDTO( season:'2010', score:2 )

def seasons = [ score1, score2, score3 ]

return [ 'seasons':seasons ]
```

And in your view, you can use it:

```
<g:select name="score" from="${ seasons }" />
```

Is this closer to your goal now?

Comment: yeah almost,just need to add few things